# Recent Documents

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa

Searched everywhere but didn't find a way of doing this in sandbox:

How can I get a list of all the recent files (system wide) in osx ?

Answer (score 2):

They are stored in `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.recentitems.plist` file.

You need the temporary entitlement `com.apple.security.temporary-exception.files.home-relative-path.read-only = Library/Preferences`

you need to manually read the plist using NSDictionary because the CFPrefs API fails -> it always tries to open the pref in your sandbox folder and you cannot specific a PATH for the file

Comment: @Daji-Djan is this practice allowed by apple ? A temporary exception to access recent files, has anybody had luck with that ? Or is there maybe a different way like running a search query to find all "last used" documents?

Comment: Good to know, I will delete my speculative answer.

Comment: it is allowed on an indivudal basis. before review you have to state why and when you use that exception. I have had luck with it but it IS a gamble... anyway, it's the only way I know :/ Even the LSSharedFileList API (which is even better and makes it EASY PEASY :D!) _fails in sandbox._

Comment: Yeah, we used LaunchServices before, but it is really no good way, because it only allows 10 items to get pulled out. But only if the user has set it to 50 in system prefs, which is normally 10, it is possible to get more. So that way really stinks.
Is there a limit of items for /com.apple.recentitems.plist ?

Answer (score 1):

The way that *doesn't* involve hard-coding pathnames would be to use LSSharedFileList. The list in question is `kLSSharedFileListRecentDocumentItems`.

If the list is incomplete or the sandbox blocks access to it, I recommend [filing a bug](https://bugreport.apple.com/).

Comment: tons of ppl have filed it.. it is basically just another wrapper around the user defaults in a way and it does not seem to get fixed anytime soon :(

Comment: @Daij-Djan: Many APIs are a wrapper around user defaults or some other file access; that doesn't mean you should be accessing user defaults/the relevant files directly instead.

Comment: no, you are right, I was saying that to say it is the same bug I explained above :) I dont disagree that it would be the suitable approach IMO -- though cocoa coder also has an issue with this api :)